# How do I get all child nodes of an element , including text ones, in Selenium WebElement?

Tags: java, html, selenium

I have to parse this element in a Java Selenium application:

```
<span class="text-small-teaser d-none d-sm-inline-block cut-job-address swissdev-grey-text">
    <span class="icon-building mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="mr-3">Altex Romania </span>
    <span class="icon-map-marker mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
    Global City Business Park, Bucharest  
    <span class="green-text"> + Remote</span>        
</span>
```

I want to get a list with all its 5 children, including the text one.
When I use any selector from WebElement, either xpath, cssSelector, it only returns me the 4 non-text elements.
Does anyone know how to do that? I'm a newbie with Selenium, i haven't worked with it before. Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean you are not able to extract this text node `Global City Business Park, Bucharest` ?

Comment: Yes, I thought it is obvious ...

Answer (score 0):

`Global City Business Park, Bucharest` is **NOT** a child node of the parent `span` node like the other 4 `span` nodes.
This text value is a text of the parent node itself.
So if for example, you want to extract the text of the second child `Altex Romania` you will be able to locate the second child element with XPath like this

```
"//span[contains(@class,'cut-job-address')]//span[@class='mr-3']"
```

And extract the text from that `WebElement` object.
However to extract the `Global City Business Park, Bucharest` you will have to extract the text from parent element itself, something like this:

```java
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'cut-job-address')]"));
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String parentStringOnly = jse.executeScript("""
    return jQuery(arguments[0]).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
    }).text();
    """, element);
```

Comment: This is not what OP is asking, see this line `I want to get a list with all its 5 children, including the text one`, your answer is more about text extraction. and he is right there are 5 child nodes however one of them is a text node not tag based node.

Comment: As I described in my answer, it is not 5 children elements there. There are only 4 child elements while the text is not a node inside the parent node, it is a text attribute value of the parent node itself. I also added the solution how to extract that text without the children elements texts

Comment: I used Jsoup before Selenium and this was not happening there, the text nodes were considered also children and were returned by the childNodes() or children() methods... why is this not the case in Selenium?

Comment: @user17693777 this is not Selenium, it's XML. I don't know what XML structures are you talking about, but here I clearly see 4 nodes inside the parent node, not 5 child nodes. The text is not a child node, it is an attribute of the node itself.

Comment: @Prophet: Not sure what is your understanding of this, but there are 5 nodes. However one of them is a text node.

Comment: In your solution itself you've mentioned this `return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE` ? Do you understand what a `Node.TEXT_NODE` is?

Comment: OK, I agree with this point

Comment: @Prophet is it necessary triple quotes instead of one? is it part of the scripting code, or what/why else...?

Comment: I saw such JavaScript syntaxes several times. I can't clearly say if it can be changed by single quotes. I don't not really know JavaScript

Comment: But the script here is correct, I copied it from some other well accepted answer